# Как сохранить вывод из консоли в файл?

Tags: java

Есть некоторый метод типа void, который выводит в консоль ряд строк, строк много.
Нужно все, что будет выведено в консоль, сохранить в файл, но при этом не переписывать метод. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Ну, можно начать с прочтения учебной литературы.

Comment: Хороший совет=) Я только учусь и читаю литературу, но все же не смогла найти ответ, а он нужен срочно, поэтому и обратилась сюда. Надеюсь на понимание)

Comment: java Main >file.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
// Создаём поток для сохранения выводимых данных
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

// Сохраняем оригинальный поток вывода
PrintStream originalStdOut = System.out;

// Заменяем поток вывода на наш буфер
System.setOut(ps);

// Вызываем функцию, вывод которой нужно перехватить
someFunction();

// Восстанавливаем оригинальный поток вывода
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(originalStdOut);

// Сохраняем в файл перехваченные данные
try (OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("some_file.txt")) {
    baos.writeTo(fos);
}
```

Comment: Я новичок совсем в этом, простите, если задам глупый вопрос. Я не вижу тут создания файла, в котором будет это все хранится. Он ведь не был создан с помощью кода?

Comment: Нет, не был. Был создан поток вывода, который можно сохранить в файл. Вы не знаете как это делается?

Comment: Не знаю. Мое задание сейчас еще не стоит в изучении таких тем. Я делаю код для вывода в консоль ряда массивов, которые будут потом использоваться в Exel для сортировки и анализа. Строк вывода может быть миллион или больше. Они не помещаются в консоли и, естественно, теряются.  Нужно весь вывод сохранить в файл.

Comment: @ОльгаПриймак я дополнил ответ, но лучше бы вам просто воспользоваться перенаправлением вывода в консоли.